# How to load collection only with specific attributes?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2

I try to load collection with specific attributes this way:

```
    $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')->addAttributeToSelect('name');
```

It adds to `_selectAttributes` field with these two attributes, but when I try to load items - nothing changed, all items have all fields... So, it's same as `addAttributeToSelect('*')`

**What should i do to resolve this issue?**

Answer (score 0):

may be try $collection->setStoreId(2) (narrow collection to your store)
or/and ->addAttributeToFilter('name', 'FOONAME')

Answer (score -1):

```
 $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
 $collection->getSelect()
    ->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
    ->columns(['entity_id', 'sku']);
```